# How to serialize/deserialize hyper::Request and hyper::Response?

Tags: rust, hyper

Hyper provides API that abstracts you away from serialization/deserialization (they pretty much do it internally and send the result over the wire).

In most cases, it's great. However, for my case, I need to be able to serialize/deserialize them to/from byte array (or maybe as an alternative to/from AsyncRead/AsyncWrite). And I need it in the form how it's send on the wire (including HttpVersion, Uri, Headers, Body).

- I am aware that I can get all these parts of the request (or response) separately. However, I don't want to duplicate serialization/deserialization functionality by implementing it on my own
- I saw https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/hyper/client/conn/index.html which looks kind-of similar to what I need to do. However, it looks like it's more designed to work over TCPStream (however, I could be wrong about it).

Comment: By serializing, do you mean converting the request/response object into the bytes that would be sent to the server/client as part of doing the request? Or just serializing it into, say, JSON for loading later?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I meant serializing it into/from bytes.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it means to (de)serialize? For instance, it's not clear how to turn `HeaderMap` or `Version` into a more primitive type.

Comment: @BallpointBen When I say "deserialize" I mean to take a byte array or AsyncRead and produce out of it hyper::Request. Somewhere internally hyper does just that. It reads out the data from the wire and create hyper::Request. I am pretty much trying to figure whether I can get to that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP server (like Hyper) needs to read part of the HTTP message in order to process an HTTP request (for routing it needs the URI part and `Content-Length` header for reading the body). So a part of the incoming byte stream is already consumed and you need to rebuild that part. The body part is easy because it already gives you the byte stream you want.

What you want is similar to a reverse proxy. [proxy-hyper](https://github.com/smyrgeorge/proxy-hyper)

There is a problem with handling the raw request bytes for requests because it may be `HTTP/1.1` or `HTTP/2` which are different. If you want something simple you can use `let (parts, body) = req.into_parts();` to create the request string. [HTTP Request Format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages)